# Inequality on the exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, inequality, exponential-function

By playing around, I seem to have come across the following inequality, valid for all $x$:
$$x-(1-e^{-x}) \ge e^{-\frac{2}{x}} x$$
(The constant $2$ is not necessarily the tightest one possible.)

Is there an easy way to prove this, and if so, is this inequality known in the literature?  The closest I have been able to come across is
$$x-(1-e^{-x}) \ge e^{-\frac{1}{x}} x$$
valid for $x\in[0,1]$ (see e.g., Mond and Paciric, "Inequalities for exponential functions and means, II", NAW, 2000. [www.nieuwarchief.nl/serie5/pdf/naw5-2000-01-1-057.pdf](http://www.nieuwarchief.nl/serie5/pdf/naw5-2000-01-1-057.pdf))

Comment: I would try the following: the first derivative of the left expression is $1+\exp(-x) > 0$ while the derivative of the right side is $-\exp(-\frac{2}{x}) < 0$. Then, consider the limits when $x\to 0$.

Comment: I believe the derivative of the RHS is $e^{-2/x} + 2e^{-2/x}/x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x<0$ the after replacing $x$ by $-x$ we need to prove that
$$e^x-1-x\geq-xe^{\frac{2}{x}},$$ which is true because 
$$e^x-1-x>0>-xe^{\frac{2}{x}}.$$
Now, let $x>0$.

Thus, we need to prove that $f(x)>0$, where
$$f(x)=e^{-x}+x-1-xe^{-\frac{2}{x}}.$$
Indeed, $$f''(x)=\frac{x^3e^{-x}-4e^{-\frac{2}{x}}}{x^3},$$
which for $x^3e^x-4e^{-\frac{2}{x}}=0$ (or $x=0.511...$) get's a maximal value of $f'(x),$ where
$$f'(x)=1-e^{-x}-\frac{e^{-\frac{2}{x}}(x+2)}{x}.$$

Thus, 
$$f'(x)>\min\left\{\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}f'(x),\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f'(x)\right\}=0$$ because two these limits are equal to zero.

Id est, $$f(x)>\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}f(x)=0$$ and we are done!